# QueryTypeBuilder<> in .net core 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

My Current Project was in old version now I Upgrade the framework to .net core 6. there were some package as well which i was upgraded:

1. Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore (6.0.25) - After upgrade
2. Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.SQLServer(6.0.1) - after Upgrade
3. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection(6.0.1) - After Upgrade

Now Problem once I upgrade all issue start coming to Entity Framework:

> - The type or namespace name 'QueryTypeBuilder<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> - 'ModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and no accessible extension
>   method 'Query' accepting a first argument of type 'ModelBuilder' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I just want to know is there any solution of above issue in .net core 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.querytypebuilder-1?view=efcore-3.1), the QueryTypeBuilder is obsolete, you should use EntityTypeBuilder instead.

For query method, you could also follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.query?view=efcore-3.1) to modify the codes based on your codes.

Like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFModeling.EntityProperties.FluentAPI.Required;

internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    #region Required
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Url)
            .IsRequired();
    }
    #endregion
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

More details about how to create a model inside the ef 6, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/).

Comment: Thank you for your update. I used that Framework but there is one query which is not working after changes. currently it implemented like this: 
modelBuilder.Query<T>()
     .ToQuery(() => Query<T>().FromSql(
         @"SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT From Employee)
     );

I changed this Query:
modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
     .ToQuery(() => Entity<T>().FromSql(
         @"SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT From Employee)
     );

Entity<T>().FromSql -> this one give me the error

Comment: Use like this   `modelBuilder.SharedTypeEntity<T>("T").ToSqlQuery(@"SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM Employee");`

Comment: @nittinaggarwal , any update? Did this codes help you? Is there any other error?

Comment: Actually I tried to use it but getting the error. here is the query:
modelBuilder.SharedTypeEntity<T>("T").ToSqlQuery(@"SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM Employee", attr.Category, attr.Group);
and the error is: No "ToSqlQuery" take 3 arguments.